# Linq extension method select not in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Good day,

I am working with linq extension methods, and I have a table where I need to extract a list of items from my table Courses ,except for some courses I do not want.

```
 public class Course
{
   public Course()
    {
        Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Level { get; set; }

    public float FullPrice { get; set; }

    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

}
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
//Get some courses that I do not need.
var coursesDontNeed=_dbContext.courses.where(//here goes condition);
        var coursesINeed= _dbContext.Courses.Except(coursesDontNeed);
```

Is there any way to make it with just one access to database, instead of writing two different linq sentences?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the LINQ query expression and **not evaluate/execute it** ,but use it in the second LINQ query.

```
var courseIdsDontNeed= db.Courses.Where(yourWherePredicateGoesHere).Select(a => a.Id);
var coursesINeed = db.Courses.Where(p => !courseIdsDontNeed.Contains(p.Id) ).ToList();
```

When you call the `ToList()` or `ToArray()` on the second LINQ query, the linq expression will be executed and there will be only one SQL statement (*which has the filtering logic to exclude those items*) generated and executed against the db.

Replace `yourWherePredicateGoesHere` with your actual predicate to filter. For example,

```
var courseIdsDontNeed= db.Courses.Where(a=>a.IsActive).Select(a => a.Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

create a temporary variable to store the `_dbContext.Courses` represented as a list and then operate on that.

```
var temp = _dbContext.Courses.ToList();
var coursesDontNeed = temp.Where(condition)...
var coursesINeed = temp.Except(coursesDontNeed);
```

in this case, we only make a single access to `_dbContext` and from there on we need not to request any data from `_dbContext`.